# AdWords Google Call Conversions not replacing phone numbers

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api, phone-number, conversion-tracking

As per the [Google Documentation](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6095883?hl=en) I've implemented the call replacement code client side. When I visit the site via ad-link Google Tag Assistant lights up green with no errors for the Website Call Conversion Tag when I append `#google-wcc-debug` to the URL to see the debug window I get the following error:

[image: google error]

The same happens if I use the callback function method. Clicking `Force` works fine and replaces the target phone number with all 9s, including the `tel:` part of the `href` in the `a` of the page.

I cannot find any documentation on this error, or any other errors for that matter. Can anyone shed some light on why the number isn't getting replaced?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Check if your call extensions are running on a schedule and if so, make sure you're testing within the schedule.

Also try testing this on a mobile device instead of desktop. Use mobile (or change your user agent to mobile) to generate the gclid and to view the landing page. See if that works.